# What is this airplane seen over Delhi?

Tags: aircraft-identification

It was flying over Delhi, India 6:41PM IST May 22 2021

[image: Zoom/crop]

Comment: This immediately says "Soviet design space"

Comment: Awesome David! I saw it, thought to myself I don't know what model this is, but it's an Ilyushin, and then saw your comment ... scrolled down, Il-76. Amazing how clearly that form language announces itself!

Comment: Isn’t this design also similar to some planes from the Royal Air Force? I ran Google Lens on this image, and it suggested an RAF plane right off the bat.

Comment: Sort of. It has the same basic form as the C-17 and A400M (t-tail, high wing, 4 engines), but other than this characteristics it’s pretty different.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That is a Silk Way Airlines [Ilyushin Il-76](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ilyushin_Il-76). Here is a snapshot from [flightradar24](https://www.flightradar24.com/2021-05-22/13:03/12x/AZQ4725/27cad144) from 13:03 UTC (6:33 PM IST) where the aircraft is approaching Delhi Airport:

[image: FR24 snapshot]

Comment: Thanks a lot kind stranger!